# Difference between "location /" and Nginx default server block values

Tags: nginx, configuration

What is the point of defining `location / { }` since, if I understand correctly this will match all potential URIs and "lose" any battle against a location with a more specific URI ?
My reasonning is you can just put all default values directly into the server block instead of defining a `location / { }`.

Hence if I am correct, this serves no purpose :

```
server {
   root /www/html;
   location / {
      root /www/html;
   }

}
```

PS: I am quite new to nginx so feel free to tell me if I could phrase things better to make the question more useful/discoverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, your specific example serves no purpose. But there are a lot of nginx directives that don't work on server-level

for example:

```
server {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

^ this does not work.
v this does.

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Server-level directives are default values. There are directives that work only in server-level, there are directives work only on location-level.

Its two fundamentally different things, it's just that your example has the same consequences.